# Xamarin Forms: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-adapter

In my Xamarin app, made using Xamarin Forms, I get the error "The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread.".

I am using a Xamarin.Forms ListView to display a list of students. When I go to the Add student page and add a student to the list, this error is thrown.

```
ListView listView = new ListView
        {
            ItemsSource = register.StudentList,
            ItemTemplate = cell // Set the ImageCell to the item template for the listview
        };

        // Set the content for the page.
        Content = new StackLayout
        {
            Children = { header, listView }
        };
```

The above code is from the Register Page, and it is where the list of students is displayed. The code below is from the the AddStudent page, and this is where a student is added to a register.

```
//Now add the new student to the register.
            if(register != null)
            {

                register.addStudent(Student);

            }               

            //After adding to the register, open up the page for this register.
            Navigation.InsertPageBefore(new RegisterPage(register), Navigation.NavigationStack.First());
            await Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
```

I am not actually using an adapter in the code, so I am not sure where this error has come from. A lot of similar questions I have seen seem to relate to android adapters, but this is an app made in Xamarin Forms.

Is there some kind of alternative that can be used in this case?

Comment: What's the type of StudentList?  Is it an ObservableCollection?

Comment: It is just a list of class type Student. A Student object holds data like name, id, etc for a student.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mention your `register` object is a `List`. Hence the view you are binding it to will never receive a message about the contents changing.

So Jason asked in the comments, whether or not `register` was an `ObservableCollection`, why you may ask yourself. An `ObservableCollection` implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`, which means when bound to a view, the view now can subscribe to the event that interface provides. This event can tell it what changed. This could be a new item was added. An item was removed or the order changed in the collection.

In turn, if you want to update an item in the collection, they must also implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in order for the view to reflect the changes made.

Comment: Ok, so by making a view subscribe to an event, it will be able to see what has been changed. I've had a look at some examples for this , but can't find anything that works for my situation yet. Do you know if there any good examples for how to implement this? Thanks

Comment: Simply replace List<Student> with ObservableCollection<Student>.  XF's databinding mechanism will automatically handle wiring everything up for you.

Comment: @Jason wow, incredibly simple! That does exactly what is required. Thanks